# What Ocarina song am I missing, and what is it used for?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

In Ocarina of time, I have the following songs:

- Zelda's Lullaby
- Epona's Song
- Song of Storms
- Sun's Song
- Saria's Song
- Song of Time

I also have all of the songs used to travel to the various temples:

- Minuet of Forest
- Bolero of Fire
- Serenade of Water
- Nocturne of Shadow
- Requiem of Spirit
- Prelude of Light

Looking at the song screen, though, there seems to be a slot open for a song that I haven't encountered yet. What is it? What does it do?

Comment: what version are you playing?

Comment: @Wipqozn The 3DS version. :)

Comment: Any chance you could take a screen shot? You have all the songs which should show up there.

Comment: I just started it up, and went to take the shot - they all show up properly, and all the slots are full. Strange. I must have looked at it wrong.

Comment: Either that or you're just crazy.

Comment: That is entirely possible. :p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The complete song list is [here](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Ocarina_of_Time/Ocarina_Songs), but I don't see any there that you're missing besides the Scarecrow's Song, which doesn't show up on the list:

> The notes of this song can be composed by you. Talk to the scarecrow at Lake Hylia and play a song eight notes long. This song can be changed at any time and it is the only song that will not be recorded with the others on the Quest Status screen.